Root systems of maximally noncomact Cartan subalgebras
Let $G$ be a real reductive Lie group, and $K$ a maximal compact subgroup in $G$. Write $\mathfrak{g}$ for the Lie algebra of $G$, and $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{k}+\mathfrak{p}$ for the Cartan decomposition defined by a Cartan involution $\theta$, where $\mathfrak{k}$ is the Lie subalgebra corresponding to $K$. Take a maximally noncompact $\theta$-stable Cartan subalgebra $\mathfrak{t}$ in $\mathfrak{g}$; that is, $\mathfrak{t}\cap\mathfrak{p}$ is of maximal dimension.
It is well known that two maximally noncompact $\theta$-stable Cartan subalgebras are always conjugate by some element in $K$. However, if we are given two positive systems $\Delta$ and $\Delta'$ for $(\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{t})$, are the two positive systems conjugate by some element in $K$, or more precisely, by some element in $N_K(\mathfrak{t})$, the normalizer of $\mathfrak{t}$ in $K$?

The conclusion is false in general.
